# I am trying to replace the sheet name “2197” in the formula =SUM('2197:2194'!$G$17) with the value in cell G30

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace the formula  `=SUM('2197:2194'!$G$17)`  in cell E36 using an Indirect command. I want the “2197” replaced with the value in cell G30 (manual entry) on the same sheet. The formula in cell E36 and in E34  `=INDIRECT("'"&($G$30)&"'"&"!$G$17")`  both work correctly, so it appears the reference cells are OK. I have tried the formula shown in the Formula Bar for E35  `=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&$G$30&":2194'!$G$17"))` but I am obviously doing something wrong. Can you please suggest how I can achieve this.

[image]

Comment: INDIRECT doesn't understand 3D references.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, using `LAMBDA()` helper function `REDUCE()`:

```
=SUM(
    REDUCE(
        0,
        INDIRECT(
            "'" &
                SEQUENCE(
                    G30 - 2194 +
                        1,
                    ,
                    G30,
                    -1
                ) & "'!G17"
        ),
        LAMBDA(x, y,
            VSTACK(x, y)
        )
    )
)
```